# how to arrange tables in specific place grid.arrange

Tags: r, pdf, grid, r-grid

I am using the gtable and gridExtra packages to manipulate PDF. I am struggling with setting the place manually for my tables i.e I would like to be both of the more in the center not so close to the edges. The place is set up automatically when the grid.arrange() formula is being used.

Additionally, I am wondering how can I make the footnote be more on the left, even "before" the table.

how can I adjust the layout_matrix() to that ?

```
grid.arrange(table1, table)
```

Please see the simplified code:

```
pdf("mrcars_check.pdf",width = 15, height=10, bg = "white", onefile = TRUE, title = "ANALYSIS OF MoM CHANGES IN BUSA MORTGAGES")


table1 <- tableGrob((format(mtcars[1:2,], big.mark = ",", digits = NULL, decimal.mark = ".", nsmALL=0, scientific = FALSE)),rows = NULL)
title1 <- textGrob(paste0("Title"),gp=gpar(fontsize=16))
footnote1 <- textGrob(paste0("Footnote"),x=0, hjust=0,gp=gpar(fontface="italic",fontsize=14))

padding <- unit(2,"line")
table1 <- gtable_add_rows(table1, 
                          heights = grobHeight(title1) + padding,
                          pos = 0)
table1 <- gtable_add_rows(table1, 
                          heights = grobHeight(footnote1)+ padding)
table1 <- gtable_add_grob(table1, list(title1, footnote1),
                          t=c(1, nrow(table1)), l=c(1,2), 
                          r=ncol(table1))

### table 2
table <- tableGrob((format(mtcars[4:9,], big.mark = ",", digits = NULL, decimal.mark = ".", nsmALL=0, scientific = FALSE)),rows = NULL) 
title <- textGrob(paste0(" Title"),gp=gpar(fontsize=14))
footnote <- textGrob(paste0("
This is a footnote.This is a footnote.This is a footnote.This is a footnote.This is a footnote.This is a footnote.This is a footnote.This is a footnote.This is a footnote.This is a footnote.This is a footnote.
                            This is a footnote.This is a footnote.This is a footnote.This is a footnote.This is a footnote."),x=0, hjust=0,
                     gp=gpar(fontface="italic",fontsize=14))

padding <- unit(2,"line")
table <- gtable_add_rows(table, 
                         heights = grobHeight(title) + padding,
                         pos = 0)
table <- gtable_add_rows(table, 
                         heights = grobHeight(footnote)+ padding)
table <- gtable_add_grob(table, list(title, footnote),
                         t=c(1, nrow(table)), l=c(1,2), 
                         r=ncol(table), clip='off')

print(grid.arrange(table1, table))

dev.off()
```

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Could you show us how `table1` and `table2` were constructed?  You don't need to show the real tables, just something similar.

Comment: It's not reproducible.  You didn't show us what packages you're using (I believe they are `gridExtra` and `gtable`), and more importantly, we don't have your `xxx` dataset.

Comment: Hi, hope now is all good. Thanks!

Comment: If you add `library(grid); library(gtable); library(gridExtra)` at the start, it would now be executable.  Hopefully you'll get an answer!

Comment: I've played with your example a bit, unsuccessfully.  I think `layout_matrix` should probably match what the base graphics `layout` function uses, e.g. `layout_matrix = matrix(c(NA,NA, 1,2, NA,NA), ncol=3)` should center them on the page.  However, I'm not seeing that.  Maybe you need to contact the `gridExtra` package maintainer.